# jsoup checking if a table exsists

Tags: java, jsoup

I have

Element list = doc.select("table").get(0);

some times there is no table present, but I am still doing get so I am

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

How to get out of this exception?
there is no size as this is element

Comment: If you want it inline so badly , you can use this : `Element list = doc.select("table").isEmpty()?null:doc.select("table").get(0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)** is the object returned from a select.

```
 Elements tables = doc.select("table");
```

and it has a [size](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#size%28%29) method. 
So you can call:

```
 tables.size();
```

Comment: event better, it has an `isEmpty()` method

Comment: I am able to do this..but want to know how I can do using element only.

Comment: @TheLearner: and what is this, then: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#isEmpty() ?

Comment: That is elements. I am looking for element. looks  there is no way in Element? only elements we can do that

Comment: @TheLearner: doc.select("table") returns Elements, elements.get(0) returns Element. but if elements is empty it throws the exception. you should try separating the calls over two lines.